# simple mysql trigger, cannot find the syntax error. appreciate for it

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin and got a syntax error from my trigger part. I followed examples online but didn't see anything wrong. Does anyone see the syntax error? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_T BEFORE INSERT ON dataT
for each row begin
    IF(NEW.id IS NOT NULL)
     SET NEW.id = 9999;
    END IF
end;
```

mysql reports that:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NEW.id = 9999' at line 4*

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing **THEN** keyword.

MySQL Reference Manual: 
[**IF Syntax** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

And for your next questions. Yes, you need a semicolon following the END IF

And you need to specify a delimiter other than the default semicolon. e.g.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ...

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```